# error to get notifications on mobile using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, service, android-notifications

I am developing an chat-app using firebase. I am using service to send notification to mobile if any child is added to database. But I am unable to get notification by this code. Messages are sending and receiving properly. 
here is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:name=".Appli"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
        );
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
    } else {
        // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
        // a welcome Toast
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        // Load chat room contents
        displayChatMessages();
    }
    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

            // Read the input field and push a new instance
            // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .push()
                    .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                    .getCurrentUser()
                                    .getDisplayName())
                    );

            // Clear the input
            input.setText("");
        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Close the app
           finish();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "You have been signed out.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                        // Close activity
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
  //  if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_clear)

    return true;
}
private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            if(!messageUser.getText().toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    .getCurrentUser()
                    .getDisplayName()))

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

MyService.java file

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

int NOTIFICATION_ID;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            ChatMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);

            if (!message.getMessageUser().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    .getCurrentUser()
                    .getDisplayName())) {

                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyService.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("New Message from " + message.getMessageUser())
                        .setContentText(message.getMessageText())
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setLocalOnly(false);
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: notification recieved");

                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

            }
        }

    });
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
}
```

I'm beginner.Please help me out.

Comment: I guess `startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));` should be in the `else` of `if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)` and in the `onActivityResult`

Comment: Is it necessary to stop the service once it is started?

Comment: I think no, dont remember. But now you are not starting the service because the place where you places `startService`

Comment: I changed by code accordingly.But  now i 'm getting repetitive notification for same message when I am moving up and down in my chat app. How can I solve this problem?